# what's the difference between executing linux commands by ssh tool and adding commands to my program?

Tags: linux, networkmanager

I configure both a static IP and dhcp on a NIC of Orangepi Zero by creating two connections in NetworkManager-connections. The installed system is armbian Ubuntu.

In my program, I use the `popen` function to set up different connections in different cases, the code is shown in the following: eth0 is the dhcp connection name and eth0:1 is the static connection name.

```
def configure():
     if platform.system()== 'Linux':
          os.popen('nmcli con up eth0:1')
          fd = os.system(u'ping 192.168.10.8 -c 4')
          if fd ==0:
              app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
     else:
         os.popen('nmcli con down eth0:1')
         os.popen('nmcli con up eth0')
     # [...]
```

By this method, the two connections are able to work in their respective situation, but the program would be stopped. The following is the main function. The wifi_connection, p.connect and u.connect are implemented successfully. but after implementing correctly the last code l.stop(), the program would be shut up by force automatically.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        l = LED()
        t = threading.Thread(target=configure)
        t.start()
        count = 1
        if os.path.isfile('settings.txt'):
           with open('settings.txt', 'r') as f:
           settings = eval(f.read())
           while True:
                 if settings['ssid'] is None or settings['psw'] is None:
                      break
                 else:
                      ret = wifi_connect(settings['ssid'], settings['psw'])
                      count += 1
                      if ret:
                           os.system('sh ./route.sh')
                           break
                      elif count == 3:
                           break
           l.t = 1
           while True:
                ret = p.connect(115200)
                if ret:
                     break
                ret = p.connect(250000)
                if ret:
                     break
           time.sleep(5)
           l.t = 0.1
           while True:
                 ret = u.connect(settings['ip'], settings['eid'], settings['pw'])
                 if ret:
                      break
           time.sleep(5)
           l.stop()
```

However if I just implement nmcli commands by SSH tool manually, without the code above in the program, the program would not be stopped and work correctly without any problem. I really don't know why. Could anyone tell me the reason?

In our project, we need to set the network configuration automatically in program, is there anyone know how to do it?

Comment: When you say " the program would not be stopped" or "the program would be stopped" above are you referring to forced termination of your program or are you referring to a blocking command?

Comment: It means forced termination. Sorry for the vague description. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Looking over your python script, there are a couple of things you could do to make your code easier to debug. Also, when asking for help, it is really helpful to include any error messages your system is generating when the program execution is halted. I would recommend checking the return value of all system calls and possibly adding debug statements (prints) to see where your program is failing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! Through several tests, we found if the nmcli commands are implemented before starting the program, the program would not be terminated. So we use a shell script to check network status to up or down the connections.